# Angular custom filter and indexOf condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, indexof

I'm new to computers and trying to build a custom filter for an AngularJS App.

I have to search a string of intergers (cultivos.age) and return the item if the string contains the mes.age condition. I've managed to make a workingFilter that returns  == values. But i can't manage to write an 'indexOf' condition so that it returns the item if mes.age is contained in the cultivos.age array

The working filter:

> ```
>     angular.module('calendarioFilters',[]).filter('filtroMes', function(){
>     return function(cultivos, name){   
>     var arrayToReturn = [];        
>     for (var i=0; i<cultivos.length; i++){
>         if (cultivos[i].age == this.mes.age) {
>             arrayToReturn.push(cultivos[i]);
>         } 
>     }
>     return arrayToReturn;
> };
> ```
>
> });

and the not working filter:

> ```
>     angular.module('calendarioFilters',[]).filter('filtroMes', function(){
>     return function(cultivos, name){
>     var arrayToReturn = [];        
>     for (var i=0; i<cultivos.length; i++){
>         if (cultivos[i].age.indexOf(this.mes.age) !== -1)  {
>             arrayToReturn.push(cultivos[i]);
>         } 
>     }      
>     return arrayToReturn;
> };
> ```
>
> });

I'm calling the filter in HTML

```
     <li ng-repeat="cultivo in cultivos | filtroMes:''">
```

Console logs "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" even in the working filter.

Thanks!

Comment: change this angular.module('myFilters',[]) to angular.module('myFilters'), otherwise creating the second filter will unbind the first filter. the [] causes the module to be redefined from scratch.

Comment: How are you calling the filter? Could you add a jsfiddle or plunker with an example?

Comment: Why do you have `>= -1` in your `if` statement? That basically says "grab everything". So I wouldn't think that the end result is undefined, but instead everything

Comment: Also, why are you using `items` in the first filter, but `data` in the second?

Comment: Thanks for your reply: i've edited the question with your remarks, to see if it is clearer. I still can't make the second filter to work.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
if (item.age.indexOf(this.mes.age) >= -1) {
```

to:

```
if (item.age.indexOf(this.mes.age) !== -1) {
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. That was one mistake, but apparently not the only one. The filter still is unfunctional.